# Updating document properties using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am using a SharePoint Designer workflow to upload documents to a SharePoint library. I also want to use the same workflow to update the document's properties (metadata), but that doesn't seem to be so easy as it sounds. I cannot see any action to update properties when using a text-based workflow editor.

I hope I am wrong and somebody here would be able to guide me where to find it. If not, are there any workarounds available?

New addition 13/01/18:
The workflow is triggered from a list which then uploads multiple documents to the library. Is there a way to identify the newly uploaded docs and then update their properties?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Update List Item is the most powerful tool in the SPD arsenal, and will allow you to set multiple metadata fields all at the same time. There is also the "Set Field in Item action, which is less powerful but faster to write to.

Limitations: it only works on the "current item" - which is whatever item the workflow was started on unless you write code to shift the focus, and it only allows setting one metadata field at a time.

Comment: The workflow is triggered from a list which then uploads multiple documents to the library. Is there a way to identify the newly uploaded docs and then update their properties?

Comment: yes, you'll need to make an internal variable (or variables - your implementation may vary) that carries the internal SharePoint ID of each document, then you'll need to use the UpdateListItem action to send metadata to each document.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the action called "Update List Item"

More info: http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-create-update-list-item-actions.htm